Flutter dependency
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:freerasp/talsec_app.dart'.
I am trying to create the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
Library package: freerasp/talsec_app.dart
Package: freerasp/talsec_app.dart

Have you followed the instructions here? Also, what's the name of your project (does it clash)?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The issue is due to missing package. To troubleshoot the error, properly add the package to the project. Follow the below steps:
Mostly two ways to add package to project:

Using the terminal
 flutter pub add freerasp



and Add a corresponding import statement in the Dart code.

Using command palette in VS code


ctrl+shift+p (for Windows users)


Cmd+Shift+P (for Mac users)

and search for " Dart : Add Dependency " option. Then enter package name and hit enter.
Now, Successfully the package is added.
If still the error persists, then run following commands:
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter pub upgrade    //(Run if need to upgrade packages)

and restart the code editor.
source : https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages
